# mongodb different TTL for every document

Tags: mongodb, ttl

as far [i know](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), currently mongodb TTL are managed by expireAfterSeconds index and it's setting for all document inside a collection.

so is there any built-in way to set expiration to single document ?, thankyou

Comment: The TTL index is a general index. On that you are totally right. But the time to live is still computed on a per document basis since it's set based on a specifc field against which the index will be evaluated. Is that what you need? Or do you actually want to specify a different length of the ttl on a per document basis?

Comment: @ManuelZelenka i want more like redis, TTL/expireAfterSeconds  specified in single document

Comment: Then you're good to go with Kevins answer. Setting expireAfterSeconds to 0 and then simply defining in the indexed field of the document when it should expire is the way to go.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On each documet you can set a field of `expires` and create the following index:

```js
db.docs.createIndex( { expires:1 }, {expireAfterSeconds: 0 } );
```

documents inside this collection will get removed once time ticks over the expired field. However, this may take up 60 seconds as the background task that runs to remove documents runs every 60 seconds.

Here's an example though...

So let's insert a bunch of documents adding 60 seconds to each document each time we add them.

```js
> var expires = new Date(); // Gets the current datetime.
> expires.setSeconds(expires.getSeconds() + 60)
1587812623023
> db.docs.insert({expires})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> expires.setSeconds(expires.getSeconds() + 60)
1587812683023
> db.docs.insert({expires})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> expires.setSeconds(expires.getSeconds() + 60)
1587812743023
> db.docs.insert({expires})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418de00f07c4d6461090b"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:03:43.023Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e300f07c4d6461090c"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:04:43.023Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e600f07c4d6461090d"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:05:43.023Z") }
```

Now if we add the TTL index.

```js
db.docs.createIndex( { expires:1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

Then we can monitor our collection each 60 seconds and see each document getting removed.

```js
> new Date()
ISODate("2020-04-25T11:03:28.278Z")
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418de00f07c4d6461090b"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:03:43.023Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e300f07c4d6461090c"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:04:43.023Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e600f07c4d6461090d"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:05:43.023Z") }
```

Nothing has been removed yet.

```js
> new Date()
ISODate("2020-04-25T11:04:18.652Z")
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e300f07c4d6461090c"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:04:43.023Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e600f07c4d6461090d"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:05:43.023Z") }
```

One document has gone.

```js
> new Date()
ISODate("2020-04-25T11:05:17.705Z")
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea418e600f07c4d6461090d"), "expires" : ISODate("2020-04-25T11:05:43.023Z") }
```

Another is gone.

```js
> new Date()
ISODate("2020-04-25T11:06:31.390Z")
> db.docs.find()
>
```

and we're left with no doucments in our collection.

Comment: I spent zero time thinking about a solution to this :) Thanks Kevin and thanks SO!

Comment: In Mongo 5.0+, `expireAfterSeconds` must be set to 1. If you set it to 0 it will default to disabling TTL expiration.

Comment: Hey @VladFr, I can't find anywhere in the docs explaining this? can you provide a link please? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time

Comment: @KevinSmith, can you please explain, how this solution works? Why don't documents expire right after insertion? Why MongoDB has to wait until time will be greater than expires key? I've looked into the documentation, but could not figure this out.

Comment: @BorisKalinin The `expireAfterSeconds` on the index is the time it'll wait after the datetime of the field specified, because we set `0` it will expire at the datetime field. This is all also done on a background thread which reads the values of the index then deletes them when expired.